# How to upgrade OpenSSH from 6.6.1p1 to version 7.2p2 on Amazon Linux?

Tags: amazon-ec2, openssh, amazon-linux

How to upgrade OpenSSH from 6.6.1p1 to version 7.2p2 on Amazon Linux?

The upgrade is required to fix "OpenSSH Xauth Command Injection" vulnerability. 
Pasting from Scan results from https://pci.qualys.com:

```
Result: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1 detected on port 22 over TCP.
```

Proposed Solution: "Users are advised to upgrade to the latest version of the software available. Refer to OpenSSH 7.2p2 Release Notes for further information."

1)Linux version

```
ec2-user@demotair.arabidopsis.org$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-24-127 4.9.38-16.33.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 20 01:31:29 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

2) Current ssh version on it:

```
ec2-user@demotair.arabidopsis.org$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015

ec2-user@demotair.arabidopsis.org$ yum list | grep openssh
openssh.x86_64                      6.6.1p1-33.66.amzn1            @amzn-updates
openssh-clients.x86_64              6.6.1p1-33.66.amzn1            @amzn-updates
openssh-server.x86_64               6.6.1p1-33.66.amzn1            @amzn-updates
openssh-keycat.x86_64               6.6.1p1-33.66.amzn1            amzn-main
openssh-ldap.x86_64                 6.6.1p1-33.66.amzn1            amzn-main
```

3) Attempt to update results in "No packages marked for update"

```
ec2-user@demotair.arabidopsis.org$ sudo yum update openssh
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                                                                     | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
amzn-updates                                                                                                                                  | 2.3 kB  00:00:00
No packages marked for update
```

PS Below links did not help me to upgrade:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=679779#679779 "OpenSSH 7 is not available via yum update"

https://serverfault.com/questions/749199/updating-openssh-on-amazon-linux-amazon-repository-out-of-date 
quote: "Until Amazon updates its package, you can stop the bug from affecting you by adding the line UseRoaming no to /etc/ssh/ssh_config on any machine from which you will be using the ssh client."

Comment: It's probably better to use Ubuntu to avoid these kinds of issues. I wouldn't use Amazon Linux again without good reason, most of their packages are well out of date.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need. As was stated in the question to which you have linked, Amazon backports security fixes, and your scanner is giving a false positive by testing for the version number rather than actually testing for the presence of the vulnerability. CVE-2016-3115 was fixed in [Amazon openssh](https://alas.aws.amazon.com/ALAS-2016-668.html) version 6.6.1p1-23.60 on 16 March 2016.